# How to create a fast data transfer between two tcp sockets

Tags: c, sockets, select, tcp, tunnel

Can someone please help on what I can do to make this simple TCP socket transfer code fast?

I have tried changing the buffer size and non blocking / blocking sockets. Nothing helps. It is much slower than a ssh tunnel. I only have 2 TCP sockets to deal with so I assume select() is not the issue. TRANSFER_BUFF_SIZE of
1000 seems to work the best. Have no idea why.

Thanks in advance

```
/* Sends data to the specified non blocking tcp socket. data_size is in bytes.
* Returns true if successful */
bool send_non_block_tcp_socket_data (int socket_id, void *data, int data_size)
{
  int i, n;
  fd_set write_fds, err_fds;
  timeval tv_delay;
  char *ptr;

  if (socket_id == -1) return false;
  ptr = (char*) data;

  tv_delay.tv_sec = 10;
  tv_delay.tv_usec = 0;

  i = 0;
  while (i < n)
  {
    FD_ZERO (&write_fds);             //clear set
    FD_SET (socket_id, &write_fds);   //add socket_id to set

    FD_ZERO (&err_fds);             //clear set
    FD_SET (socket_id, &err_fds);   //add socket_id to set

    while (select (socket_id + 1, NULL, &write_fds, &err_fds, &tv_delay) == 0)
    {
      tv_delay.tv_sec = 10;
      tv_delay.tv_usec = 0;
    }

    if (FD_ISSET (socket_id, &err_fds) != 0) return false;
    if (FD_ISSET (socket_id, &write_fds) != 0)
    {
      n = send (socket_id, &ptr[i], data_size - i, 0);
      if (n == -1) return false;
      i += n;
    }
  }
  return true;
}

/* Sets the tcp socket as non blocking */
bool set_tcp_socket_non_blocking (int socket_id)
{
  unsigned int op;

  op = fcntl (socket_id, F_GETFL);
  //sbit (&op, O_NONBLOCK);
  op = O_NONBLOCK;
  fcntl (socket_id, F_SETFL, op);
  return true;
}

/* Reads tty output into the specified buffer.
* Returns number of bytes read or -1 on error*/
int get_non_block_tcp_socket_data (int socket_id, char *buffer, int buffer_size)
{
  int n;

  if (socket_id == -1) return -1;
  if ((n = recv (socket_id, buffer, buffer_size, 0)) > 0) return n;
  if (errno == EAGAIN) return 0;  //no error, just no data
  return -1;
}

/* Waits for the specified tcp sockets to have data to be read.
* Returns socket that has data ready or -1 on error */
int wait_read_tcp_sockets (int socket_id, int socket_id2)
{
  int n, id;
  fd_set read_fds, err_fds;
  fd_set sid_set;
  timeval tv_delay;

  if (socket_id == -1) return -1;
  if (socket_id2 == -1) return -1;

  id = socket_id;
  if (id < socket_id2) id = socket_id2;
  while (true)
  {
    FD_ZERO (&read_fds);
    FD_SET (socket_id, &read_fds);
    FD_SET (socket_id2, &read_fds);

    FD_ZERO (&err_fds);
    FD_SET (socket_id, &err_fds);
    FD_SET (socket_id2, &err_fds);

    tv_delay.tv_sec = 10;
    tv_delay.tv_usec = 0;

    n = select (id + 1, &read_fds, NULL, &err_fds, &tv_delay);
    if (n != 0) break;
  }
  if (n > 0)
  {                       
    if (FD_ISSET (socket_id, &err_fds) != 0) return -1;
    if (FD_ISSET (socket_id2, &err_fds) != 0) return -1;

    if (FD_ISSET (socket_id, &read_fds) != 0) return socket_id;
    if (FD_ISSET (socket_id2, &read_fds) != 0) return socket_id2;
  }
  if (n < 0)
  {
    fprintf (stderr, "wait_read_tcp_sockets() select error\n");
  }
  return -1;
}

/* Transfers data between two TCP sockets
*
* Return true if successful */
bool transfer_data_tcp_sockets (int socket_id, int socket_id2)
{
  int n, si, read_sid, write_sid;
  char buffer[TRANSFER_BUFF_SIZE+4];
  bool read;

  set_tcp_socket_non_blocking (socket_id);
  set_tcp_socket_non_blocking (socket_id2);

  while (true)           
  {
    read = false;
    n = get_non_block_tcp_socket_data (socket_id2, buffer, TRANSFER_BUFF_SIZE);
    if (n < 0) return false;

    if (n > 0)
    {
      read = true;
      if (send_non_block_tcp_socket_data (socket_id, buffer, n) == -1) return false;
    }

    //--------

    n = get_non_block_tcp_socket_data (socket_id, buffer, TRANSFER_BUFF_SIZE);
    if (n < 0) return false;

    if (n > 0)
    {
      read = true;
      if (send_non_block_tcp_socket_data (socket_id2, buffer, n) == -1) return false;
    }

    if (!read)
    {
      while (true)
      {
        read_sid = wait_read_tcp_sockets (socket_id, socket_id2);
        if (read_sid == -1)
        {
          fprintf (stderr, "wait_read_tcp_sockets() error\n");
          return false;
        }
        else if (read_sid == socket_id) write_sid = socket_id2;
        else if (read_sid == socket_id2) write_sid = socket_id;
        else
        {
          fprintf (stderr, "wait_read_tcp_sockets() returned invalid socket %d\n",
                  read_sid);
          continue;
        }

        while (true)
        {
          n = get_non_block_tcp_socket_data (read_sid, buffer, TRANSFER_BUFF_SIZE);
          if (n < 0) return false;
          if (n > 0)
          {
            read = true;
            if (send_non_block_tcp_socket_data (write_sid, buffer, n) == -1) return false;
          }
          break;
        }
      }
    }
  }
  return true;
}
```

Comment: What is the point of using an endless loop that keeps looping as long as the socket times out? You may as well just use the socket in blocking mode instead, and assign timeouts to handle slow transmissions.

Comment: All this app will do is transfer data between sockets until it is killed or an error/disconnect is detected.

Comment: All the more reason NOT to use non-blocking semantics.

Comment: How can I wait for 2 separate blocked sockets?

Comment: You can pass more than 1 socket to `select()` at a time, and `select()` works for blocking and non-blocking sockets. Simply don't read on a socket that is not readable, or write to a socket that is not writable.